# No cambian los iconos del mismo color en botones de navegacion del toolbar en android con kotlin(bottom navigation)

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, toolbar, bottom

```
[![xml de la activity][1]][1] 
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/pastel"
    app:menu="@menu/botonesnavegacion" />
  </LinearLayout>`  
 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_person"
    android:title="hello"/>

  <item
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_person"
    android:title="bye"/>
  </menu>`
[![xml del menu de botones de navegacion][1]][1][1]:
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qYFy.png

Estoy haciendo una prueba en Kotlin,
estoy intentando cambiar los colores de los iconos del bottom navigation, tambien de la parte de colors , pero no me cambian , he vuelto a crear otro archivo y tampoco me cambia el error , me gustaria tener los dos iconos del mismo color ..

Comment: Hola, a tu pregunta le hace falta el codigo,un [example] te recomiendo leer  [tour], aprender [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El color de los iconos se puede cambiar al momento de crear el .XML o posteriormente dentro del código.

Entras al archivo .XML al cual le deseas cambiar el color, posteriormente te diriges al apartado:

`android:fillColor="#3DDC84"`